# Why does the Kullback-Leibler divergence use the expected value based on the data/new distribution instead of the reference distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

The Kullback–Leibler (KL) divergence is defined as

$$
D_{\text{KL}}(P\parallel Q)=\sum _{x\in {\mathcal {X}}}P(x)\ \log \left({\frac {\ P(x)\ }{Q(x)}}\right) = \mathbb E_P \left[ \log \left({\frac {\ P(x)\ }{Q(x)}}\right) \right]
$$

where Q is the reference distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and P is the measurement distribution. In a way Q is little like a $H_0$-hypothesis in a hypothesis test. Or $D_{\text{KL}}(P\parallel Q)$ is a little bit like the model likelihood in a Bayesian setting with Q being the model and P the data.

So far my understanding.

I do not understand, why we are using the expected value $\mathbb E_P$, based on the measurements though if we consider the Q to be the reference or the true distribution and are trying to think how much P differs from the reference distribution. I would have expected $\mathbb E_Q$.

Can someone explain?

Comment: If $P\ll Q$ (that is $P(x)=0$ if $Q(x)=0$, $D_{KL}(P||Q)=E_Q\big[\frac{P}{Q}\log\big(\frac{P}{Q}\big)\big]$ Thus integration is over $Q$. Also, notice that $D_{KL}(P|Q)$ is optimum when $P=Q$.

Comment: @Mittens: I do not understand. Why does the KL divergence switches $mathbb E_P$ into $mathbb E_Q \frac1Q$ for $P<<Q$? Also, why is this relevant to my question? I mean: If using your argument, and not $P<<Q$ and we still integrate over P.

Comment: Your concern was why expectation is taken with respect to $P$. I am saying that that is an "illusion" since $E_P[\log(P/Q)]=\sum_x\log\Big(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\Big)\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}Q(x)=E_Q[\log(P/Q)P/Q]$. It is the function $\eta(s)=s\log(s)\mathbb{1}_{s>0}$ what defines the KL-divergence of $P$ relative to $Q$. This is related to what physicists called relative entropy. The second comment is to show that if one deviates from the "base" measure $Q$, $D_{KL}$ becomes positive (when $P=Q$, $D_{KL}(P|Q)=0$.

Comment: @Mittens: When looking at $_[log(/)/]$, I might still ask, why not using $_[log(/)/]$ ? Where does $()=log()>0$ appear in the KL divergence; what is $s$? The second comment, I understand.

Comment: Here is a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) article that touches on this.

Comment: @Mittens: I am sorry, but this confuses me more than it enlightens me. Rephrasing my original question: Why is $\sum_x () \cdot log( () / ())$ used instead of $\sum_x Q() \cdot log( () / ())$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151207/discussion-between-mittens-and-make42).

Comment: @Make42 does the "interpretations" section of Wikipedia help? E.g., is the expectation under the real distribution of the number of bits required to encode it (assuming a reference) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Interpretations

Comment: @ClementC.: Not really. My point is, I understand that Q is the "real" or the "reference" distribution. Otherwise, P would be in the denominator (in the log).

Comment: In the coding theory application, you draw data from the world, it comes from $P$ (true real-world one), and you want to encode it according to your ideal/reference model $Q$. So the expectation is with respect to $P$, as you want to say "on average, for data I observe from the real world, how much is the encoding cost if I assumed $Q$ as a reference"

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary of my discussion with the OP. It is by no means the best possible answer to the OP's question and may not be as intuitive as I think. As I will indicate later in this posting, integration with respect to $P$ ($\mathbb{R}_P$) in the expression of entropy is in fact integration with respect to the reference measure $Q$ ($\mathbb{E}_Q$), but of a slightly different expression.

The KL-divergence comes from the notion of entropy (information) developed in information theory by Shannon (1948). The concept of entropy dates back to Clausius (1850's) in Thermodynamics. It was von Newman ([legend](https://www.eoht.info/page/Neumann-Shannon%20anecdote) has it) who suggested  to Shannon to adopt the name of entropy for his information quantity as the expression that defines it had  already been developed in Physics, and because noone understands what entropy really is and so the name would help in debates and discussions.

---

**Entropy**

In information theory, entropy is a way to measure with one ingle number the level of uncertainty of probabilistic systems. There are now several ways to derive the concept of entropy for probability distributions (on a discrete space) starting from some ideal properties, to some axioms and then to a characterization of the object. Shannon's derivation of his concept of information (or entropy) lead to some axioms. He defined *entropy* as a function $H$ on the set of probability measures $\mathbf{p}$ on a discrete space, say $\mathbb{N}$, ( used $\mathbf{p}(i)=p_i$) such that
0. $H((1))=0$,

1. $H$  is continuous in the $p_i$ (I'll be vague here)
2. For any $n$ define the probability measure $\mathbf{p}^{(n)}$   such that  $\mathbf{p}^{\{n\}}_j =  \frac1n$, for $1\leq j\leq n$. Then $g(n)=H(\mathbf{p}^{(n)})$ is a  strictly monotone increasing function of $n$.
3. If a choice be broken down into two successive choices, the original $H$ is the weighted sum of the individual values of $H$: if $\mathbf{p}=(p_1,\ldots,p_n,p_{n+1},\ldots, p_{n+m}))$ and $r=\sum^n_{j=1}p_j$, $s=\sum^m_{j=1}p_{n+j}$, then
   $$H(\mathbf{p})=H((r, s))+r(H(p_1/r,\ldots,p_n/r))+ sH(p_{n+1}/s,\ldots,p_{n+m}/s))$$
   Under this conditions (axioms) it can be shown that
   \begin{align}
    H(\mathbf{p})=-k\sum_i p_j\log(p_i)\tag{0}\label{H}
   \end{align}
   for some constant $k>0$. For the time being, let use set $k=1$.

There are several other axiomatizations that lead to the same expression for entropy. Among them, there is the one developed by soviet mathematician Khinchin in the 1950's (a little later than Shannon) and which is used in many courses in Information Theory and bears more resemblance to the concept of entropy in thermodynamics or Statistical Mechanics, in particular the miraculous additive property of entropy of uncommunicative systems.

---

**Abstraction of entropy on measure spaces**

For those with basic knowledge of abstract integration theory, notice that behind the development of \eqref{H}, there is an underlying measure space $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}},\#)$ where $\#$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, that is $\#(A)$ is the number of elements in $A$. Every probability measure $\mathbf{p}$ on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ has a density function $p(n)=\mathbf{p}(\{n\})$ with respect to $\#$, thus, \eqref{H} can be expressed as
\begin{align}
H(\mathbf{p})=-\mathbf{E}_\mathbf{p}\big[\log(p)\big]=-\int_{\mathbb{N}}\log(p)\,d\mathbf{p}=-\int_{\mathbb{N}}p(n)\log(p(n))\,\#(dn)\tag{1}\label{H1}
\end{align}

With this in mind, suppose $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a measure space and that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite (this assumption is to allows the use densities or Radon-Nikodym derivatives or densities of measures with respect to $\mu$). Let $\mathcal{P}_\mu$ the family of all those probability measures on $(X,\mathscr{F})$ that are dominated by $\mu$ (i.e. absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$). Each measure $\nu$ in $\mathcal{P}_\mu$ has a (unique $\mu$-a.s.) density which is typically denoted in measure theory by $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. That is $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ is the measurable function on $X$ such that
$$\nu(A)=\int_X\mathbb{1}_A\,\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,\mu(dx),\qquad A\in\mathscr{F}$$
In analogy to \eqref{H}, we define the entropy of $\nu\in \mathcal{P}_\mu$ (with respect to $\mu$) as
\begin{align}
H_\mu(\nu):=-\mathbb{E}_\nu\big[\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\big]=-\int_X \log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\nu=-\int_X\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\mu\tag{2}\label{AH}
\end{align}

Define $\eta(s)=-s\log(s)$, $s>0$ and $\eta(0)=0$. Then
$H_\mu(\nu):=\int_X\eta\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\mu$. It is easy to check that $-\eta$ is continuous and convex on $[0,\infty)$ and thus, for any $v,w>0$
$$\eta(w)\leq\eta(v)+\eta'(v)(w-v)=-w\log(v)-(w-v)$$
This, for any densities $f$ and $g$, i.e. nonnegative measurable functions on $X$ such that $\int_Xf\,d\mu=1=\int_Xg\,d\mu$,  we have
$$-\int_X f(x)\log(f(x))\,\mu(dx)\leq -\int_X f(x) \log(g(x))\,\mu(dx)$$
This is in a sense one of the known properties  of entropy as discussed above, namely that if $\mathbf{p}$ is a probability measure on  $\mathbb{N}$ supported on a set of cardinality $n$, then $$H(\mathbf{p})\leq \log n$$
In fact, when $0<\mu(X)<\infty$,  $g(x)\equiv\frac{1}{\mu(X)}$ is a density w.r.t $\mu$. Hence, if $\nu$ is the measure with density $f$,
\begin{align}
H_\mu(\nu)\leq \log(\mu(X))\tag{3}\label{max}
\end{align}
with equality of $d\nu=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}d\mu$.

---

***Relative entropy or Kullback-Leibler divergence***

Based on the abstraction of entropy made above, suppose $\nu$ and $\mu$ are probability measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{F})$. If $\nu\in \mathcal{P}_\mu$, then we define the ***relative entropy*** of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ as
\begin{align}
H(\nu|\mu):=H_\mu(\nu)=-\int_X\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\nu=-\int_X\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\mu\tag{4}\label{RH}
\end{align}
This quantity  allows for  comparison of probability measures on a common measurable space $(X,\mathscr{F})$ (under some dominance assumptions).
Using expectation to denote integration we have that
$$H(\nu|\mu):=-\mathbb{E}_\nu\big[\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\big]=-\mathbb{E}_\mu\big[\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\big]$$
As $\mu(X)=1$, it follows from \eqref{max} that
$$
H(\nu|\mu)\leq 0
$$

The ***Kullback-Leibler*** distance (or divergence) of $\nu$ relative to $\mu$ is defined by $$D_{KL}(\nu|\mu):=-H(\nu|\mu)$$
The change of sign is due to the fact that the word *distance* is used. Notice however, that $D_{KL}$ is not really a distance in the sense of metric spaces.

To conclude this posting, suppose that

- $\nu$ and $\mu$ are probability measures on $(X,\mathscr{F}\big)$,
- $\nu\in\mathcal{P}_\mu$,
- and that $\mu\in \mathcal{P}_\gamma$ for some $\sigma$-finite $\gamma$ measure on $(X,\mathscr{F})$.

Then $\nu\in\mathcal{P}_\gamma$. Denote by $f$ and $g$ the densities of $\nu$ and $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$, that is $f=\frac{d\nu}{d\gamma}$ and $g=\frac{d\mu}{d\gamma}$. The properties of densities (chain rule) shows that $f=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\frac{d\mu}{d\gamma}=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \,g$. Hence
\begin{align}
H(\nu|\mu)=-\int_X\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\mu=-\int_X f\,\log\big(\frac{f}{g}\big)\,d\gamma=-\int_X\frac{f}{g}\log\big(\frac{f}{g}\big)\,g\,d\gamma\tag{5}\label{five}
\end{align}
Identity \eqref{five} or rather its negative, is the formula is another expression that appears in the literature.
It is convenient to identify measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ in $\mathcal{P}_\gamma$ with their densities (w.r.t. $\gamma$). For this reason, often in the literature the notation $H(f|g)$ is used for $H(\nu|\mu)$ where $f$ is the density of $\nu$ and $g$ is the density of $\mu$ with respect to an underlaying $\sigma$-finite measure $\gamma$, and $\nu\in \mathcal{P}_\mu$.

---